# node mysql not executing query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm having trouble executing my update query. Right now it's inside the select query witch works fine, the update queries are well formed, since I can copy paste a single update query from the output and it will update accordingly. no errors thrown, stream with update string appear but none are executed.

```
connection.connect();


connection.query('SELECT text, id from twits2 order by id ASC', function(err, rows) {

    rows.forEach(function(row){
        var id = row.id;
        var r1 = sentiment(row.text);
        var score = r1.score;
        var comparative = r1.comparative;


        var q = 'UPDATE twits2 SET score ="'+score+'", comparative ="'+comparative+'" WHERE id="'+id+'"';
        console.log(q);
        connection.query(q, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
        });
});
```

Comment: Do you have a `connection.end()` somewhere in your code ? Do you check for `err` ?

Comment: Side note: As a rule you really shouldn't concatenate arguments to make a query. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I know, At this point I'm just trying everything, making sure the query was well formed.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I don't have a connection end. Where should it go? It doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions

pay attentions to the beginTransaction and commit functions being called there before and after the queries.

Comment: @ChicoDelaBarrio This looks like it. Thanks!